# What should I do to connect to remote jms queue?

Tags: jboss, jms, jndi

I have working **JBoss AS 7 (7.1.1 final)** server on localhost with some queue.

And I want to connect to that queue in a desktop application.

So I wrote something like this:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) 
initialContext.lookup("RemoteConnectionFactory"); // <- there is it fail
```

But it results in this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could
>   not obtain connection to any of these urls: remote://localhost:4447
>   and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException:
>   Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
>   Receive timed out] [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server
>   remote:1099 [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server
>   remote:1099 [Root exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   remote]]]

Of course, I have **jbosscall-client.jar** in class path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "hlib");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password1");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(properties);
ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
```

This code workl well if 'application user' for jboss have been added.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `remote` in the `PROVIDER_URL` with `jnp` something similar to

```
### JBossNS properties
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=jnp://localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

Comment: change for that: env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099"); and still give same exception

Comment: @Hib change your provider url to env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:4447");

Comment: change to jnp://localhost:4447. still get: Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 127.0.0.1:4447 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to retrieve stub from server 127.0.0.1:4447 [Root exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000000C]]